# How can I rewrite this code so that it gives me the same result in less than one second?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

```
For[i = 1; list = {}, i <= 23456, i++, 
 l = AppendTo[list, i/Pi]]; Total@N@list
```

Comment: `Sum[N[i/Pi], {i, 23456}]` takes 0.00096 seconds on my machine

Comment: We can all learn from Gauß: `N[# (# - 1)/(2 Pi)] &[23456]` does this in 4 flops.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Strictly speaking this is different: rather than rounding the sum, OP rounds each summand before summing up.

Comment: So even worse... ^^

Comment: Well maybe - at any rate, results differ by 7466.28

Comment: (Sorry, "rounding" was a wrong word to use here)

Comment: First and foremost would be to avoid `AppendTo`. For reasons behind that, check the documentation.